# CSS Import Font-face difference

Tags: html, css, font-face

The main text ("Elegance is sublime.")  for the site doesn't have quite the right font for some reason. I am looking at my design and live version and they are different.

The head-scratching issue for me is, unless the font is distorted why does it look different. Sizing aside the font is clearly different. Suggestions?

https://github.com/marcoantonio123456/Studio

[Live version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgkGz.jpg)

[How it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smVZo.jpg)

```
        @font-face {
          font-family: 'Stem-Regular';
          src: url('components/typefaces/Stem-Regular.ttf') format('ttf'),
        }

        .headline-top { position: relative;
            font-family: 'Stem-Regular', sans-serif;
            font-size: 7.8em;
            letter-spacing: 0.8px;

            left: 90px;
            top: 350px; 
            z-index:1;
```

Comment: Did you try inspecting it and see if the font is calling the correct one?

Comment: Use your Browser inspector. Can you show us a URL of the live site?

Comment: marcoantonio.netlify.com

Comment: How can I inspect what font is being called under the browser inspector. I am looking for it right now. What is the option called?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because The issue is that the font loaded is not the font wanted by the Topic Poster. This is not a code issue and can only be resolved by the Original Poster installing and loading the correct font files.

Comment: The head-scratching part is that it is the exact font file used on Sketch ('Should be" Image) where I designed the site is the font file loaded. I checked twice. That's why I turned to see if my CSS code was off. I want to thank you for the answer non the less. I will re-download the font or simply use another typeface. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you Martin, I am still learning and I am definitely noticing how complex fonts can be. I just wanted to make sure the error was not on my side. Thanks for the support non the less

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The head-scratching issue for me is, unless the font is distorted why does it look different. Sizing aside the font is clearly different. Suggestions?

## Summary:

The font you have is not Stem Regular. Despite the file name claiming to be so.

## Details:

The font in your (correct) screenshot is not the same font as on [your website](http://marcoantonio.netlify.com). Your website correctly displays the `'Stem-Regular'` font as loaded from `'components/typefaces/Stem-Regular.ttf'` . Whether this is actually the font with this name, is doubtful.

I have copied your font and used it on a word document and the font displays as your website does. There is nothing wrong with you code or the loaded font file.

The font you have - according to several online font depositories - is **NOT** the same as Stem Regular, or Stem Regular W03.

You can view Stem Regular W03 here: [Fonts.com](https://www.fonts.com/font/paratype/stem/regular), [Online Web Fonts](https://www.onlinewebfonts.com/download/60bb18a25a964a9cc419b599a50267ad) note the `a` character is different to your website.

## Solution:

Find the correct Stem Regular from another depository or chase up whoever you got this font from. We can not help you as this is not a code issue.